# priority queue in Python using comparator

Tags: python, comparator, priority-queue

Is there any way exists that can do the *java* **queue priority comparator.comparingInt** method in **Python**?

I want the node which has a higher priority  come to the front of the queue.

edited:
for example:

```
class node:
  def __init__(self, label, priority):
      self.label = label
      self.priority = priority
  




node1 = node('a', 3)
node2 = node('b',2)
node3 = node('c', 1)
 
nodes in queue comes like this==> (node1,node2,node3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Albin states, you'll need to use the `heapq` module (unless you want to write your own heap implementation from scratch). One very important thing to note is that this library gives only an implementation of a min-heap, rather than a max-heap.

To write a comparator for a custom object, you'll need to override the `__lt__` function (the function that's called when the `<` operator is used). So your node class would look like this:

```py
class node:
  nodes = dict()

  def __init__(self, label, priority):
      self.label = label
      self.priority = priority
  
  def __lt__(self, other):
      # Note that we've reversed the operands here, since we want a max-heap.
      return other.priority < self.priority
```

Then, we can make a heap as follows:

```py
import heapq

heap = []

node1 = node('a', 3)
node2 = node('b', 2)
node3 = node('c', 1)

heapq.heappush(heap, node1)
heapq.heappush(heap, node2)
heapq.heappush(heap, node3)

# Should print 'a', 'b', 'c' in that order.
for i in range(3):
    print(heapq.heappop(heap).label)
```

Comment: thanks mate, that was very useful (:

Answer (score 0):

You should look closer on this documentation regarding priority queues (heapq for python3):
https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heapify

It refers to the priority queue and also have basic examples of sorting based on a value inside a tuple.

Comment: i have edited this post. could you check it again?!